# Headers when posting from Angular 10 using Ionic/Cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

We developed an app on Ionic previously using Cordova which posted information to an API with headers set including credentials set as HTTPS_AUTH. This worked fine but we needed to update for a few reasons.

We have refactored this to a newer version of Ionic and Angular but it seems the headers are not being sent properly.

within the .ts we are bringing in the libraries:

```
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
```

Construct

```
constructor(private router: Router, private storage: Storage, private modalCtrl: ModalController, private http: HttpClient) {
```

We build the headers:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('HTTPS_AUTH', this.APIKey).set('example', '1')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8').set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

When I log the headers using

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(headers));
```

I get:

```
{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate[{"name":"HTTPS_AUTH","value":"xxxxxx","op":"s"},{"name":"example","value":"1","op":"s"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"application/json; charset=utf-8","op":"s"},{"name":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin","value":"*","op":"s"}],"headers":{},"lazyInit":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}}}
```

But it seems that when I send the post to the endpoint:

```
this.http.post('https://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/api/v2/add_permit', body,  headers ).subscribe(data => { **good results here** }, error => { **errors show here**};
```

I end up with the post being unauthorised before it gets a chance to view the body as the HTTPS_AUTH header is not being received.

I note that within the headers logging there is at the end an option of "headers":{} which suggests to me that the headers are not being set properly but I am at a loss how to.

I have attempted to create the headers directly:

```
const headers = { headers: { HTTPS_AUTH: this.APIKey, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}};
```

but this gets blocked by CORS where the previous approach passed CORS

Any pointers gratefully received!

Many thanks

Comment: Have you considered creating a `HttpInterceptor`?

Comment: Not really, it's just challenging this was working fine prior to the update of the core and now it seems to have this issue. I was hoping there is a simple something I am missing... I'll take a peek at an HttpInterceptor and se what it is/does. thanks.

Comment: Setting headers manually as object key/value pairs does the trick, but it's unclear why previous working approach with HttpHeaders is now broken. Looking through angular git history for the headers file I see nothing that would result in this breaking change. Would be great to find a solution that works with our previous approaches, but it seems like HttpHeaders is broken in Angular 10+